# Imprimir fecha actual de una forma especifica

Tags: c, linux, date, shell

quiero guardar en un tipo time_t la fecha actual siguiendo este formaro "Nov 13 21:15" osea, "Mes NumDia Hora", con este codigo he conseguido el siguiente resultado: "11 13 21:15" :

```
time_t t = time(NULL);
struct tm *tm = localtime(&t);
char time[100];
strftime(time, 100, "%m %d %H:%M",tm);
```

Si sabes como hacer para que ponga el nombre del mes en vez del numero me ayudaria, lo mejor seria que funcione con el mismo codigo que tengo porque buscando por google encontre solucion pero no lo hacian de la misma forma la parte de time(NULL) y eso.
Gracias!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Puedes utilizar la opción %b de la función [strftime](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/c_standard_library/c_function_strftime.htm):

```
time_t t = time(NULL);
struct tm *tm = localtime(&t);
char time[100];
strftime(time, 100, "%b %d %H:%M",tm);
```